# React component function returning JSX causes error when used in render method of ES6 class React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, jsx

I have a function that returns JSX as shown below:

```
  function struct(locals) { 
    return (
      <View style={fieldsetStyle}>
        {label}
        {error}
        {rows}
      </View>
    );
}
label, error, and rows are functions that also return JSX.
```

I call this function within the render method of an ES6 class component

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const locals = this.getLocals();

    return struct(locals); 
  }
}
```

When I run the code, I get error

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a 
  class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render 
  method of `Struct`

How can I get the result from struct function to render as return value of Component class render?

Comment: Do you have a good reason for having this as a separate function? Why you don't turn it into a `LocalsView` component and render it passing `locals` as prop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are returning a react component, not a react element. The difference is an element describes how to create the component, where as the component is the instanced class. You need to `return React.createElement(Struct);`, or `return <Struct/>`. Also, your `locals` variable will actually be a `props` object. So your code should look like this:

```
function struct({locals}) { 
    return (
      <View style={fieldsetStyle}>
        {label}
        {error}
        {rows}
      </View>
    );
}

class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const locals = this.getLocals();

    return <Struct locals={locals}/>; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to import that function as an ES module into your class component.

```
import { struct } from '..path/to/struct';
```

Then your render function which should return some JSX which is syntactic sugar. You should place your intermediary variables before the return statement in your render method. It's safer to wrap it inside a `div` if you have multiple elements.

```
  render() {
    const locals = this.getLocals();
    return (
      <div>
        struct(locals);
      </div>
    );
  }
```